# Problems reading from locally hosted video stream

Tags: python, opencv, flask, raspberry-pi, stream

I am streaming video from a Raspberry Pi via flask to a locally hosted location, in this case 192.168.0.81/5000. This part works fine, and I am able to view the stream from any device on the same network, at said address. I am now trying to read that stream into python using cv2, with the intention of then embedding that live video into a Dash webapp. However, I cannot get it to work.

This is (part of) the code I am using to try and create the VideoCapture. Video_feed is the name of the HTML video object created on the Pi. The Pi is streaming the video in mjpeg format.

```py
import cv2

vid = cv2.VideoCapture('192.168.0.81:5000')
result, image = vid.read()
cv2.imshow('',image)
```

This is my error:

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0)
> D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:971: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in
> function 'cv::imshow'

I have also tried specifying the video object at the address with 192.168.0.81:5000/video_feed (which is the name of the stream when it uploads from the Pi) but this gives error:

> (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name
> of file): 192.168.0.81:5000/ in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'

I have also tried a large number of variations of the address including file extensions, and using udp://@... and tcp://@... but all of these result in the first error shown.

I am fairly new to python, and still trying to work out what is going on, so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Since the cv2.VideoCapture function will return a video (a set of streaming images), to access each of those images you would need to loop through the images in the stream. Here is an example in the source code of opencv. https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/4.x/samples/python/video.py

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It ended up being easier to change the stream to rtsp instead of mjpeg following the method shown in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else struggling with a similar issue, I ended up solving this by changing the stream from flask to rtsp, following the steps in this link:
[https://www.howtoraspberry.com/2022/02/real-time-streaming-protocol-and-the-raspberry-pi-video-for-linux-2/#:~:text=Enable%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi%20Camera,Enter%20and%20reboot](https://www.howtoraspberry.com/2022/02/real-time-streaming-protocol-and-the-raspberry-pi-video-for-linux-2/#:%7E:text=Enable%20the%20Raspberry%20Pi%20Camera,Enter%20and%20reboot).

In a terminal window enter the following:

```
apt -y install cmake liblog4cpp5-dev libv4l-dev git
git clone https://github.com/mpromonet/v4l2rtspserver.git
cd v4l2rtspserver/
cmake .
make
sudo make install
```

Start the stream with the following:

```
v4l2rtspserver -W 1920 -H 1080 -F 15 -P 7447 /dev/video0
```

where -W and -H set the resolution of the stream, -F sets the framerate, -P sets the port, and /dev/video0 is the address of the PiCamera in the RaspberryPi. Access this stream by opening VLC and clicking File -> Open Network Stream, then entering this address:

```
rtsp://video.local:7447/unicast
```

where video.local is your RaspberryPi IP address.

You can use the following code to access the video stream using Python:

```
import cv2
cap = v2.VideoCapture("rtsp://root:pass@RaspberryPiIP:Port/stream_name")

while(cap.isOpened()):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame', frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(20) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

where the IP was the same as originally posted in the question, the port was specified as 7447 from the link above and the stream name was unicast, again specified by the link above.

Comment: Consider including the steps for changing the stream from flask to rtsp in this answer. In future, by doing so, if the link becomes unavailable, people will still be able to solve this problem.